# Script works in development environment, but not in production

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am running an angular app. I am having the strangest effect ever...

I am calling a backend which returns a json. I parse that json and build an object structure client side. It works perfectly in dev but the exact same code does provide strange effects on prod. See code inline comments for hints. The only thing I could think of is that the data comes different from prod...

I can't see what's wrong, as it's the exact same code, and it's driving me completely nuts, probably the worse thing I ever saw in 10+ years programming!

Basically the json structure is a list of objects, every object has a reference ID, and several objects are correlated by the same reference ID - I need a structure where I'd access all objects with the same reference ID.

Maybe I'll make a fool of myself here but I really can't see it...I just ran the data in two JSON validators and both say the data is **valid**.

```
app.factory('ItemService', ['ItemProvider', function(itemProvider) {
  var itemSrv;
  var obj_by_id = {};  //create empty object

  itemSrv = function(callback) {
    itemProvider.get_data()
      .success(function(data) {  // callback ok, data has json content
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
          obj = data[i];         // I get the object in the json
          if (! (obj.identificador in obj_by_id)) {
            obj_by_id[obj.identificador] = {};   //build a key in the object if not already available
          }
          obj_by_id[obj.identificador][obj.campo_nombre] = obj; //assign the object by keys
          console.log(obj_by_id); **//HERE obj_by_id is ALWAYS EMPTY!!!! BUT ONLY ON PROD!!! On dev works fine...**
        }
        callback(obj_by_id);  //Here I would get the whole structure, but it's empty on prod...
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        console.log("Error getting data from server");
      });

  }
  //factory function body that constructs shinyNewServiceInstance
  return itemSrv;
}]);
```

EDIT: console.log(data) right after success, on request
dev:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6MP3.png

prod:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfwvc.png

EDIT2: you can have a look at the returned data here (will remove this link later!): http://bibliolabs.cc/milfs/api.php/ison?id=2
I am concerned about all those \u unicode chars, could that be an issue?

Comment: Can you please show the http response (dev and prod)? use your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Have you debug it in browser?

Comment: I see that the response from prod has Content-Encoding "gzip", while dev has "text/plain;charset=UTF-8".

Comment: another difference is that dev is getting its data directly from an apache/php server, while prod has an intermediate nginx

Comment: how about console.log(data); right after the success? compare the results between dev and prod

Comment: What happens when you try to fetch the same json file?